# arrays in C (mixing two arrays)

Tags: arrays, c, function, for-loop, merge

I can't figure out why is my program not working. Can someone from the experts help? :)`
I'm getting storage junk numbers in my console, my third array should be a mix of array aA[] and aB[], first goes the elements from array aA[] then from aB[] once at the time.

``````````````````````````````````
// 2te Vektor HÜ
// Bsp.: aA[7, 8, 9]  aB[14, 15, 16]
// =>    aC[7, 14, 8, 15, 9, 16]
// returns size of C`int val = 0;
`````````````````````````````````   
int Mischen(int aA[], int aB[], int aC[], int aLaenge) {
    
    int val = 0;
    val = aLaenge;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < aLaenge; i++) {

        int c = 0, x = 1;
        c = c += 2;
        x = x += 2;

        aC[c] = aA[i], aC[x] = aB[i];


    }
    
    return val;
}
``````````````````````````````````

Comment: `c = c += 2;` is the same as `c += 2;`

Comment: @SouravGhosh except that it *isn't*. `c = c += 2` has undefined behaviour because there is no sequence point.

Comment: `int c = 0, x = 1;` should be placed before the loop. And `c += 2; x+= 2;` should be placed after `aC[c] = ...;`

Comment: What purpose does `val` serve, and why are you returning it?

Comment: @klutt To make an importance of the program. val means valuable.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Before I got the joke, I really wanted a dose of your medication :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the code like this way, you should defined the variable `c` and `x` outside the loop and every time increase them by two.

```
int Mischen(int aA[], int aB[], int aC[], int aLaenge) {
    
    int val = 0;
    val = aLaenge;
    
    int c = 0, x = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < aLaenge; i++) {

        //int c = 0, x = 1;
        //c = c += 2;
        //x = x += 2;

        aC[c] = aA[i];
        aC[x] = aB[i];
        
        c += 2;
        x += 2;

    }
    
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simplify the loop. Remember, you need to copy the values from the source arrays to the alternate index in the destination array. To elaborate,

- `aA[0]`, `aA[1]`, `aA[2]`.. should go to `aC[0]`, `aC[2]`, `aC[4]`...
- `aB[0]`, `aB[1]`, `aB[2]`.. should go to `aC[1]`, `aC[3]`, `aC[5]`...and so on.

So the logic can be

- Copy the value at `aA[i]` to `aC[2*i]`.
- Copy the value at `aB[i]` to `aC[(2*i)+1]`.

So, change it to

```
for (int i = 0; i < aLaenge; i++) {

    aC[2*i] = aA[i];
    aC[(2*i)+1] = aB[i];

}
```